# CSS background-image

Tags: css

I have a landing page with a background image that is showing on locally, but when I push it out live I am unable to see it on the internet.

My file structure is very simple, I have a root folder called runn, and in that folder I have a css folder, an image folder, and etc.

Below is the css for my background image.

```
body {
    color: white;
    background: #ee6184;
    background-image: url('../images/image_01.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 180%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Did you push the images out there too?

Comment: Have you checked if the image downloading in the browser is getting a status code of 404 (file not found)? Do this by using the networks tab in the developer inspector (cmd + option + i on mac or f12 in most windows browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the browser console (or network), maybe it shows you 404 error for this image. That means your path does not work for the server, and also it can be 403 (forbidden) or other errors.

Also, you can set path as `/images/image_01.jpg` if the root is not in subfolder like this: `domain.com/runn/`.

In other ways please put the link, so I can understand the issue.

Comment: the link to my site is, www.expressrunn.com

Comment: Ok, I've found two issues. first one is image url is set to `images/image_01.jpg`, so it will dig in `css/images/` folder. Second and general thing is that http://www.expressrunn.com/images/image_01.jpg image does not look to render. Double check that image, maybe you need to upload it one more time to the server.

Comment: I just reloaded it to the server again. And I just changed the url to ../images/image_01.jpg. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

usually when debuging an image isn't showing as expected, go chrome console see if there is 404 saying resource can't be found.

```
background-image: url('../images/image_01.jpg');
```

that means there is no such file exist in the path u've written in your html. 
then re-configure the image path or upload the resouces to the correct path.

u can either use relative path in css as you've done in this case

```
background-image: url('../images/image_01.jpg');
```

or you can use absolute path in a sever language file such as in php

```
background-image: url('<?php echo site_url();?>/images/image_01.jpg');
```